# Chinese tourist L visa and visiting Hong Kong

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong

I'm an Australian visiting China, I want to make a trip for a day or two to Hong Kong while I am in Shenzen. I would return to Shenzen afterwards.

It seems I need a double-entry visa for this, but one condition of the double-entry visa is that you must prove incoming/outgoing flights/trains from China.

The problem is that I can't seem to find anywhere online to book the train from Shenzen to Hong Kong. It seems that it is just the regular metro. Should I look at booking a bus or something? A ferry was mentioned elsewhere but I can't find booking for that either.

Comment: Do you already have the China Visa?  Getting a 10 year multiple entry Visa is pretty much the default these days and any 'proof' is only for your initial visit.

Comment: No I don't have the visa.

Also I meant to say double entry visa, not multiple entry.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from getting a Multiple Entry Visa?

Comment: No not really, it's just slightly more expensive.

Comment: The AUD$30 extra for the multiple entry visa will make this planning much easier by essentially eliminating the need to plan so specifically.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm actually applying from the UK but i'm sure the price difference is similar.

Comment: I strongly suspect that if you just write KCR (Kowloon Canton Railway) on the application you'll have no problems, provided you have your return flight to Oz booked.

Comment: I'm flying back to the UK (I'm a student there). Also after doing some more research, it seems that multiple entry visas are less likely to be given. I might see if I can book some kind of bus or ferry from shenzen->hongkong.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment I think if you write KCR in the application you'll have no problems provided your international flights are booked and you provide the bookings and accommodation bookings.

If you want to book a bus, it's not a bad way of getting to/from Hong Kong. There are also ferries which may make sense in some circumstances (maybe if you are staying in She kou. The land crossing at Luo hu can be very, very busy, especially on weekends and holidays. Last time I looked the bus companies' websites were in Chinese only, but if you are staying in Shenzhen that's probably the least of your problems.

Answer (score -1):

There are no trains from Shenzhen in Mainland China to Hong Kong...yet.

From Shenzhen, the easiest thing to do would be cross at either Luohu or Futian which are pedestrian crossings with MTR stations on the other side.

When applying for the China Visa, you don't have to show every future entry, just the initial entry and exit, but they don't even hold you to that.

Comment: There are trains from Hung Hom station in Hong Kong to several Chinese cities. The "through train" to Guangzhou has been operated for decades. It currently goes Hung Hom to/from the GZ East station via Dongguan 12 times a day and takes a couple of hours. Eg. [this](http://www.chinatrainguide.com/guangzhou-railway-station/hongkong.html) guide. CNY 190 each way in 1st class.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany True, but the closest station is Guangzhou and OP is originating on Shenzhen.  It would be a ~90min backtrack.  I'll clarify.  Thx.

Comment: Dongguan is about 1hr 15 from Hung Hom, but still not a sensible thing to do for real. It's only [155 HKD ($20 USD)](https://www.it3.mtr.com.hk/b2c/frmFareGuangdong.asp?strLang=Eng) (Changping->Hung Hom) though if he really wanted to book a 'flight' out of the PRC. I don't think it's necessary.